# Why doesn't "auto ch = unsigned char{'p'}" compile under C++ 17?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

I'm puzzled. Isn't `const auto ch = unsigned char{'p'};` a perfectly valid initialization expression? Fails to be compiled by all three major compilers with almost identical error messages:

> error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Swapping curly braces for `('p')` changes nothing.
It does, however, compile without the `signed` or `unsigned` keyword.

**[Online demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/C1Ak4v)**

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: so does `const auto ch = static_cast<unsigned char>('p')`, but that's conversion, not initialization.

Comment: `using T = unsigned char; const auto ch = T{'p'};` seems to work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Hm, do you think the compiler simply fails to parse `unsigned char` as a single type name in this context?

Comment: `const auto ch = (unsigned char){'p'};`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Because only single-word type name could be used for this kind of [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

> A single-word type name followed by a braced-init-list is a prvalue of the specified type `designating a temporary (until C++17)` `whose result object is (since C++17)` direct-list-initialized with the specified braced-init-list.

`unsigned char` is not a single-word type name, while `char` is. And this is true for functional cast expression too, that's why `('p')` doesn't work either.

As the workaround, you can

```
using uc = unsigned char;  // or use typedef
const auto ch = uc{'p'};
```

Or change it to other cast styles.

```
const auto ch = (unsigned char) 'p';  // c-style cast expression
const auto ch = static_cast<unsigned char>('p');  // static_cast conversion
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason for this limitation? Like, if multi-word type names were allowed here, what other things would become broken?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe To be honest I don't know; I only know that the standard says so.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Because `uc{'p'}`/`uc('p')` is a functional cast.  A function name can't have a space in it so neither can the type name.

Comment: @NathanOliver A functional cast isn't really a function call.

Comment: @curiousguy For all intents and purposes it is.  If the type is a class type then the constructor is called.  the cast and call have the exact same syntax and grammar.

Comment: C-style cast, really? How about `static_cast` instead (or in case Boost is used, `boost::implicit_cast`)? The language allows a [*simple-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier) or (in a template) a [*typename-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#nt:typename-specifier), BTW, in a function-style cast, to be precise. Your statement that it "can't have a space" is slightly misleading because e.g. `std :: uint8_t` has spaces and is a valid *simple-type-specifier*.

Comment: @NathanOliver But a function style cast to a pointer or reference type can also perform arbitrary conversions like C style casts (a big design problem in C++ IMO)